# App domain is marked for unload due to memory pressure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-clr

In my sql server log (2005 SP4) I have this message every couple of seconds :

"AppDomain XXX [DataBase.dbo[runtime], YYY] is marked for unload due to memory pressure"

Our server :

- Windows Server 2003 R2 Enterprise Edition SP2
- 32 Gb RAM
- Physical Address Extension
- Intel Xeon CPU X5675 x 2 (6 core) 3.07Ghz
- Awe enabled
- We have CLR code in SQL Server
- -g2048 on startup (I'm no DBA, and this value was set by a former emplyee)

I read many article about memtoleave or vas, but I don't get how to diagnose my problem.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft has a [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969962) about this behavior. You got a 32-bit OS with 32-bit application, so the process' address space is 4 GiB. AWE can be used to access more memory, but it is limited only for buffer pool usage. As per [the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175581%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

> The SQL Server buffer pool can fully utilize AWE mapped memory;
>   however, only database pages can be dynamically mapped to and unmapped
>   from SQL Server's virtual address space and take full advantage of
>   memory allocated through AWE. AWE does not directly help supporting
>   additional users, threads, databases, queries, and other objects that
>   permanently reside in the virtual address space.

Short-term solution: review that your CLR code minimizes memory usage.

For a long-term solution, upgrade to 64-bit.

**Addendum**

Kimberly Tripp has written [a white paper](http://www.sqlskills.com/resources/whitepapers/sql%20server%20dba%20guide%20to%20sqlclr.htm) about CLR stuff from DBA point of view. She's got a few nice queries and Perfmon counters that are of use for tracking CLR resource use.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem and here is how I fixed it:

> [Don’t enable Hyper-V Dynamic Memory for your virtual machine but set it static with a value of e.g. 8GB RAM](https://teusje.wordpress.com/2015/05/07/slow-performance-on-asp-net-mvc-application-using-entityframework-sql-server/)